# how to add a message to the "featured image" meta box on Wordpress post edit screen

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

how can I add a custom message to the "featured image" meta box on Wordpress' "edit post" screen?

[image: screenshot of meta box in question]

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/edited-post-thumbnail-metabox-wont-display-correctly/

```
/**
 * Add label to post thumbnail meta box
 */
function swd_admin_post_thumbnail_add_label($content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id)
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
        $content .= '<small><i>(Add image larger than 700 x 458 px)</i></small>';
        return $content;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'swd_admin_post_thumbnail_add_label', 10, 3);
```